# Wrong Required field error message

Tags: visualforce, error-messages

This is my vF page:

```
<apex:page controller="NewNoteControllerExtension" tabStyle="Account"> 
 <apex:sectionHeader title="New Note"/>
 <apex:form >  
 <apex:pageBlock >

 <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>    
    <apex:commandButton action="{!back}" value="Back" immediate="true"/>    
 </apex:pageBlockButtons>
 <apex:pageMessages />

  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1"> 
     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="Title" for="Title"/> 
      <apex:inputText id="Title" value="{!NoteName}"  required="true" size="55"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="Body" for="Body"/> 
      <apex:inputTextarea id="Body" value="{!NoteBody}"  required="true" rows="14" cols="80"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="Select Folder" for="folder"/>
      <apex:selectList value="{!selectedFolder}" size="1" id="folder">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!Folders}"/> 
      </apex:selectList>
   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="Is Visible to Management User" for="visible"/>
      <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!IsVisibleManagement}"  id="visible" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

  </apex:pageBlockSection>

 </apex:pageBlock>

 </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

I´ve a required validation for NoteBody Property:

```
id="Body" value="{!NoteBody}"  required="true"
```

This is message showed:
[image]

Do you know how can i remove this strange text (component id?),"j_id0:j_", from the message?

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

Comment: I´m sorry. I ve voted to close this question as duplicate. I will search better next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the **label attribute** directly on the `inputTextArea`

```
<apex:inputTextArea label="Body" id="Body" value="{!NoteBody}"  required="true" rows="14" cols="80"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input , adding label on inputTextArea is giving the correct error message but so we are missing the field label. Keeping outputlabel is working all fine . Please update your answer so i can mark it like best.

Comment: @Enry  k, I updated it